# How to Skip the Object if the Condition matches in RealmResults Query

Tags: android, realm

I have a Realm List where I have to apply filter and there are certain conditions that I have to follow for the query.

Suppose there is a string Array -

```
String[] uservpaStringArray = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
```

In transObject, I have some fields. For now, we focus on two fields - "user"&"id" which could have a value from the `uservpaStringArray`.

Now I want to filter if the "**user**" has value in this `uservpaStringArray` then don't check-in "**id**" and vice-versa.

```
RealmResults<transactiondata> unique = realm.where(transactiondata.class)
                    .isNotNull("user")
                    .isNotNull("id")

                   .not()
                    .beginGroup()
                    .in("user", vpaArray, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                    .or()
                    .in("id", vpaArray, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                    .endGroup()


                    .sort("dateTime", Sort.DESCENDING)
                    .distinct("user", "id")
                    .findAll();
```

This will check both the **user** and **id** for each data. I don't want that. I could always Loop a List and then do the conditional things. But if I could do this during the Query.